# How to align list item center vertically

Tags: html, css

I can't align my list into center of my container,

Refer to the screenshot I provided. Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

[image: Here is the screenshot]

I have tried vertical-align = middle, justify content but still not center.

```css
.pink1 {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.pink1>h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

.pink1>ul {
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.pink1>ul>li {
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink1 area">
  <h6>Navigation</h6>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I expect the h6 and list are align center perfectly on the container.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DeltaTroz Please note that `padding` of ul was removed which was making it look right shifted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple use `text-align: center` to center align the text horizontally.
For vertical center, you can use `display: flex` along with `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: center`

See below example

```css
.pink1 {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*For handling elements vertically*/
  justify-content: center; /* to Align items vertically center */
  min-height: 500px; /* You can remove this. i have added  this to show the difference */

}

.pink1>h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

.pink1>ul {
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.pink1>ul>li {
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="pink1 area">
  <h6>Navigation</h6>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add only `text-align: center`, so content centers between the left and right edges.

```css
.pink1 {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-column: 2/4;
  height: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.pink1>h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

.pink1>ul {
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.pink1>ul>li {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pink1 area">
  <h6>Navigation</h6>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope! this helps