# How to align `list-style-image` in a right-aligned list?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want the `list-style-image` to appear next to a right-aligned list. How should I do this? Should I move the position or alignment?

Comment: Hey @PreciousCandy, could you include the things that you have tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your HTML as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Use flex:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Coca cola</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Arman, you forgot the images.

Comment: @BeniTrainor Hi. Yes, but it was about alignment and it should work if you add images.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `background-image` property to add images as list style image keeping `list-style-image: none`.
For example -

#### HTML CODE

```
</head>
<body>

<h1>The list-style-image Property</h1>

<p>The list-style-image property replaces the list-item marker with an image:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
ul { 
     list-style:  none;
     padding:  0;
     text-align: right;
     display: flex;
     align-items: flex-start;
     flex-direction: column;
}
li {
    width: max-content;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 85%;
}
li:before {
    content: url(sqpurple.gif);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:  middle;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

#### DEMO

[image]

#### LINKS AND RESOURCES

1. [Adjust list style image position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)
2. [How to align list item center vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964061/how-to-align-list-item-center-vertically)